Server side refresh token
General question is not framework specific, but for context, I use nextjs v14 with app router and .NET API. For auth, I set cookies for access token and refresh token. Refresh token has path set to /auth/refresh-token.
My problem and question is, if I'm server rendering profile page, where I show data about currently logged user or any other page where I fetch from API with user's access token, and access token expires, how do I refresh token?
On client side, I have axios middleware that handles token refresh and retries the original request. But when access token expires and api call fails on server, I can't call refresh token there as cookie for refresh token has path set so it's not sent on every request.
I tried redirecting to temporary page to client like /refresh-token, doing token refresh client side and then redirecting back to original url, but that looks bad. I saw that for example, youtube calls RotateCookiesPage on every request - not sure if that would be viable solution as they call that every time you refresh the page and doesn't help much if initial render fails because of token expiration.
How can I handle this? Nextjs specific answer would be awesome, but also answer in general would be sufficient so I know it's possible and can try to implement solution with Nextjs.
Thanks!

r u using next-auth?

No, I'm handling authentication manually. On login, I set access and refresh token cookies via my backend. Client side I have nextjs middleware that handle protected pages depending on the cookie and have react context where I store some auth details. I was looking at next-auth, but don't see how it would resolve my problem but just add their layers on top of it, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Hi, if you're on the server component, why don't you just call your database then and there ? Yes I know you'd be forced to do authentication and authorization at every page. But isn't that what lucia auth creator recommends you to do

Thanks for the comment! I'm trying to avoid touching backend and authentication. I'd like to keep just access jwt and refresh token, without introducing sessions. I feel like it would just add unnecessary complexity if it was just for being able to server render with user data.

It's a very interesting question and relates to separation of concerns between secured and unsecured data. Some thoughts of mine here:
UNSECURED DATA
For unsecured data, NEXT.js can duplicate data for both initial page loads and Ajax requests. You can pre-render data for a fast time to first render (TTFR) and pre-deploy it all to a CDN. You also get SEO benefits.
SECURED DATA
This has some fundamental differences:

Cannot be pre-rendered since that is not secure so you cannot get all NEXT.js benefits
Not reachable by SEO

If your SPA uses cookies to call APIs, then also calling APIs server side can add complexity. To get the server side working reliably you will need to increase cookie exposure for the refresh token, eg use a refresh cookie patb of /. Yet I don't really like that.
MY PREFERENCE
I treat secure data differently by design. I prefer to keep secure data out of the web host's logic and only make JSON requests client side, since getting secure data in two ways adds complexity.
So you might design a solution where this is the behaviour when the user reloads the page, eg with F5 or Cmd+R:

Initial page load is based on pre-rendered unsecured data
TTFR is good, followed by an API request to get secured data and dynamically update the page.

You can even go further and issue cookies on the API side of the architecture, so that the web host does not have any security and the SPA calls directly to APIs.

Thanks for the answer! Your preference is exactly what I did in my previous projects. I just wanted to try out and use as much as nextjs benefits as I could in this project, but it seems it's not easily possible when using access and refresh token.
